# Why is my APL expression returning 1 2 1 2 instead of 0 1 0 1?

Tags: apl

My expression

```
?(1 2 × 4) ⍴2
```

Is returning

```
1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2
1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2
```

but I expected it to return

```
1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
```

Why?

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing a `?` at the very left of your expression?

Comment: Ah yeah, miscopied! Good catch

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to create a random Boolean array.

```
      ?(1 2 × 4)⍴2
2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2
2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2
1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1
```

Many APL implementations have a default index origin of 1, including Dyalog.

Setting `⎕IO` (Index Origin) is one way to get your desired result:

```
      ⎕IO←0
      ?(1 2 × 4)⍴2
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

A `⎕IO`-independent way of generating random Booleans is to ask equality with 1:

```
      ⎕IO←1=?2         ⍝ ⎕IO may be 1 or 0
      1=?(1 2 × 4)⍴2   ⍝ Random Boolean matrix
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: Yeah, if `⎕IO=1`, something like `?4 8⍴2` creates an array whose internal data representation is 8-bit signed integers (so `⎕DR` gives `83`). But if `⎕IO=0`, you can get a Boolean array (`⎕DR` says `11`). But your method `1=` or `1≠` will always gives 1-bit values, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the index to 0, APL's default index is 1.

Here's how you spell, "Set index to 0":

```
 ⎕IO←0
```

Comment: APL implementations always have a default index origin, which is usually 1.

Comment: Ah thanks. Truth be told, I couldn’t find a stack overflow question for how to set the index, so I wanted to create one so next time I needed to set the index I could remember